# Adding :user_id to a resource (rails3 routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to set up routes for the "Page" model nested within the "User" model.  Only "Pages" needs to be resourcesful.  (User has_many pages)

**This is the original way I did it:**

```
resources :users, path: '', only: [] do
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
```

The above worked for me just fine.  The routes I got were these:

```
      user_pages GET    /:user_id(.:format)                 pages#index
                 POST   /:user_id(.:format)                 pages#create
  new_user_pages GET    /:user_id/new(.:format)             pages#new
 edit_user_pages GET    /:user_id/:id/edit(.:format)        pages#edit
      user_pages GET    /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#show
                 PUT    /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#update
                 DELETE /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#destroy
```

This made sense for me because `/john-doe/page1` would be `user_pages_path(@user, @user.pages.first)`.

However, new_user_pages didn't make sense because a user can only make a page for himself/herself.  Therefore, each user should visit /new, not "/:user_id/new".  Furthermore, what happens if the user visits another user's ":another_user_id/new" ? (it would make more sense to do new_pages_path and '/new' instead of `new_user_pages_path` and `/:user_id/new`).

**Another way I tried to do the above routing:**

I also realized the above can be accomplished in a shorter way due to the fact that ":users" does not need to be resourceful:

```
resources :pages, path => :user_id
```

However, this resulted in paths w/o "user" in them:

```
      pages GET    /:user_id(.:format)                 pages#index
            POST   /:user_id(.:format)                 pages#create
  new_pages GET    /:user_id/new(.:format)             pages#new
 edit_pages GET    /:user_id/:id/edit(.:format)        pages#edit
      pages GET    /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#show
            PUT    /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#update
            DELETE /:user_id/:id(.:format)             pages#destroy
```

---

What is the "rails" way of doing this?  Also, should I remove "new" from the resource and define it separately?

Also, does it make sense to use **scope** or **namespace** instead?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want your routes to follow the `new_user_pages_path` format?  There might be reasons for doing it the way you want that I'm not aware of, but for me, it's a lot easier when all of my nested resource paths follow the same format.

To answer your question about preventing a user from visiting `/:another_user_id/new`, you can prevent this by adding a `before_filter` to make sure that the id getting passed to the new action matches the id of the user that is currently logged in.

This is what I'm using in the app I'm building currently:

```
things_controller.rb

class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  #other filters
  before_filter :correct_user

  #controller methods

  private
    def correct_user
      if params[:user_id]
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        unless @user && current_user == @user
          redirect_to(root_path)
        end
      else
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
end
```

Of course, you'll need a current_user method for this to work (mine comes from devise).

Comment: Yep, I implemented something similar to your `correct_user`.  I just thought it would look simpler/better if the new page creation path is `example.com/new` rather than `example.com/johndoe/new`.